# How to solve serialisation on Dictionary<string,object> type problem

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I have an issue with my complex message type which consists of `Dictionary<string, object>` property.
This property serialize as below example;

```
"mailParameters": { "RedirectUrlKey": { "valueKind": 3 }, "FirstName": { "valueKind": 3 }, "LastName": { "valueKind": 3 }, "MerchantName": { "valueKind": 3 }, "OrderTrackingLink": { "valueKind": 3 }}
```

I don't have the same issue with the 5.1.0 version of mass-transit in our .net framework application.

Is there any configuration or workaround to solve this problem?

Comment: Seems like this question can be deleted...

Comment: Please see "[ask]" and the linked pages and "[MCVE]". We appreciate that you might be new, but we do expect evidence of the effort you've put into this. Where did you search? Why didn't it help? If it did, where is the code you wrote to test what you learned? If you didn't write code, why not? If you did, what is the minimal code that demonstrates the problem you encountered, along with the explanation of the problem, and the minimal input data and the expected result? Without that it's hard to help you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.